# How to make an array by one string in JS

Tags: javascript

I get one string by query like `'5e6,5e4,123'`.
And I want to make an array containing this query as below in JS.

```
['5e6', '5e4', '123']
```

How can I make this? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: Did you search at all for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.split(',')`

```js
var str = "5e6,5e4,123";
var array = str.split(',');

console.log(array);
```

You can read more on this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
console.log('5e6,5e4,123'.split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of split method of string like below:

`var res = str.split(',');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var query = '5e6,5e4,123';
 var queries = query.split(‘,’);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const output = input.split(',');
```